# Ninject Asp.net mvc 2 404 errors?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, ninject

When I debug my asp.net mvc 2 application and I put a break point on my action that is called when a 404 error occurs every time I  invoke any action my error action gets called but the view does not get displayed.

This is in my web.config (copied from nerddinner):

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="/Home/Trouble">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="/Home/Confused" />
</customErrors>
```

Nerd Dinner doesn't do this and as soon as I take off Ninject mine doesn't do it either.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me with Ninject and MVC2.

```
    <customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="Error.htm" redirectMode="ResponseRedirect">
        <error statusCode="403" redirect="Error.htm"/>
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="Error.htm"/>
    </customErrors>
```

Try adding redirectMode="ResponseRedirect" to your customErrors tag.